# How to find dictionary value in a pandas cell in the last position?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary

**Objective:** I am looking to add an additional column in my pandas data frame called "description" and I am interested to find only the items in "some_dictionary". Many of the values in my dictionary are also in my Pandas data frame, however, I am only interested in finding the one that is in the last position and then adding the value in the dictionary as the description to the data frame.

**Description:**
For example,
if I had a value of AA, BB, CC then I am interested in learning that CC is in the last position and then adding the value from the dictionary for the key CC. In this case that would be "Countable Cats".

My expected output would be a data frame with category, owner, description.

```
some_dictionary = {
    "AA": "Alot Anacondas", 
    "BB": "Billion Bobs",
    "CC": "Countable Cats",
    "DD": "Double Dwarfs",
    "EE": "Eleven Elfs"
}

data = {'category': ["[AA, pik(BB)]", 
                     "[(gem(BB), CC)], ril[DD]", 
                     "hur[AA, (EE)]", "zonk[EE, DD, CC, (BB], lux(AA))"], 
        'owner': ["Teagra", "Jenny", "Justin", "Ray"]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: My expected output would be a data frame with category, owner, description.

Comment: Please show to us ~ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extractall` to extract all the keys in the dictionary, and `groupby().last()` to get the last keys:

```
pattern=rf'\b({"|".join(some_dictionary.keys())})\b'

last_keys = df_1['category'].str.extractall(pattern)[0].groupby(level=0).last()

# or
# df_1['category'].str.findall(pattern).str[-1]

df_1['description'] = last_keys.map(some_dictionary)
```

**Update**: You can also use this pattern to extract the last occurrence with `str.extract`:

```
pattern=rf'(?s:.*)\b({"|".join(some_dictionary.keys())})\b'
last_keys = df_1['category'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Output:

```
                          category   owner     description
0                    [AA, pik(BB)]  Teagra    Billion Bobs
1         [(gem(BB), CC)], ril[DD]   Jenny   Double Dwarfs
2                    hur[AA, (EE)]  Justin     Eleven Elfs
3  zonk[EE, DD, CC, (BB], lux(AA))     Ray  Alot Anacondas
```